# Unique Integrity Error on Email Field (Not User model)

Tags: django, django-models

I am getting this error when trying to create a `Member` (**note that this is not the User model**) with an `email` that already exists:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "members_member_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(myemail@gmail.com) already exists.
```

The `email` field for the `Member` model looks like this:

```
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=False, primary_key=False)
```

Why am I getting this error if `unique` is set to `False` and it is not a `primary_key`? Thanks!

Comment: Was it unique before? If so, did you run migrations? Are there `constraints` in your `Member` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it was unique before. I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`. What are `constraints`? Thanks!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It worked when I deleted my local db and re created it. I have a prod db running on AWS, any ideas on commands I can do to fix this without having to delete the prod db?

Comment: can you run `ALTER TABLE members_member DROP CONSTRAINT members_member_email_key`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is there some Django command I can run instead? I am not sure how to do this on AWS?